# Removing blackarch completely from system

Tags: arch-linux

I've installed BlackArch like an idiot and not too long ago I tried to remove all files but there are still some crumbs left of it.  I tried to update the packages through the terminal and this is what I got:

```
sudo pacman -Syyu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                     148.9 KiB   242K/s 00:01 [######################] 100%
 extra                   1759.7 KiB   296K/s 00:06 [######################] 100%
 community                  5.3 MiB   568K/s 00:10 [######################] 100%
 multilib                 183.2 KiB  1263K/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 blackarch                  2.7 MiB   752K/s 00:04 [######################] 100%
 blackarch.sig            566.0   B  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
error: blackarch: signature from "Levon 'noptrix' Kayan (BlackArch Developer) <noptrix@nullsecurity.net>" is invalid
error: failed to update blackarch (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: failed to synchronize all databases
```

How do I completely remove all instances of BlackArch from my computer?  I don't want it to consistently look for its package updates!

I tried the following:

```
paclist blackarch | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs sudo pacman -R
checking dependencies...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: bind-tools: removing geoip breaks dependency 'geoip'
:: cryptsetup: removing argon2 breaks dependency 'argon2'
:: gnome-color-manager: removing exiv2 breaks dependency 'exiv2'
:: gnome-nettool: removing iputils breaks dependency 'iputils'
:: libgexiv2: removing exiv2 breaks dependency 'exiv2'
:: php: removing argon2 breaks dependency 'argon2'
```

Comment: BlackArch is a distribution. How did you install it? Did you install it as a normal OS or did you already have an Arch instance and just added the blackarch repositories?

Comment: I added the repositories

Comment: Eeeek! Don't just blindly remove everything! That's why I said "assuming you want to remove everything". Anyway, removing the repository should be enough to stop you from getting these errors when updating.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you simply added the BlackArch repositories. So, first check the packages you installed from them and see if you want to remove them:

```
paclist blackarch
```

Assuming you want to remove all of them, you can do:

```
paclist blackarch | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs sudo pacman -R
```

Then, assuming you followed the instructions [here](https://www.blackarch.org/downloads.html#install-repo) and ran the `strap.sh` script, that will have run this command:

```
cat >> "/etc/pacman.conf" << EOF
[blackarch]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/$MIRROR_F
EOF
```

So all you need to do is:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/blackarch/{N;d}' /etc/pacman.conf
```

Then, remove the list of mirrors that the script added:

```
sudo rm /etc/pacman.d/blackarch-mirrorlist
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to completely remove blackarch packages**

In this command `-R` is used to remove and `-c` is used to remove the package even if it is breaking any dependency so moral of the story is that this command will delete all the Blackarch installed packages and their dependencies

```
sudo pacman -Rc blackarch
```

after that just remove the blackarch mirrorlist **(repository)** by :

```
sudo rm /etc/pacman.d/blackarch-mirrorlist
```