# How to remove blackarch from Manjaro?

Tags: package-management, manjaro

I want to remove [Black Arch Linux](https://blackarch.org/) from my system because it's getting me some troubles at update time. I read in two different sources how to do it, but in the first step of both methods, the same trouble does not allow me to remove it.

[First method](https://edunham.net/2015/04/08/removing_blackarch.html) start with

```
pacman -Sl | grep blackarch | cut -f 2 -d " " | xargs sudo pacman -Rn
```

[Second method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532455/removing-blackarch-completely-from-system) start with

```
paclist blackarch | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs sudo pacman -R
```

... but at this point they both give me the same output

```
error: blackarch: signature from "Levon 'noptrix' Kayan (BlackArch Developer) <noptrix@nullsecurity.net>" is unknown trust
error: database 'blackarch' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: blackarch: signature from "Levon 'noptrix' Kayan (BlackArch Developer) <noptrix@nullsecurity.net>" is unknown trust
error: no targets specified (use -h for help)
```

The signature error and the database error are the same errors that I have when I try to update.

Comment: I assume "blackarch" refers to the distribution. Never heard of it, so I added a link.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked.

Edit `/etc/pacman.conf` with your text editor and go all the way down to the bottom. There should be an entry for `blackarch`, remove that and run `pacman -Syu` and you should be good to go, no more `blackarch`.