# Can I safely remove this blackarch file?

Tags: arch-linux, repository, pacman

I have added blackarch repository to my Arch Linux installation. But after some time I deleted that repository with the help of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532455/removing-blackarch-completely-from-system) question. But then I find out that there is still some blackarch file exist on the system, here:

```bash
$ sudo find / -name *arch* | grep -i black
/usr/share/pacman/keyrings/blackarch-trusted
/usr/share/pacman/keyrings/blackarch-revoked
/usr/share/pacman/keyrings/blackarch.gpg
/var/lib/pacman/sync/blackarch.db
/var/lib/pacman/sync/blackarch.db.sig
/var/lib/pacman/local/blackarch-keyring-20140118-3
```

Can I safely remove those files/folders?